# getting data from input box in form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a form I have:

```
<h1>Word game!</h1>
<form id="joke-form">
    <label>
        Unscramble these letters to form a word:<Br>
        <span class="scrambled">REYJUQ</span>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id = "userinput" size="10">
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Check</button>
</form>
```

And here is a jquery function I am running on it.  My problem is that I don't know how to get the value that the user inputs in the textbox when they press submit.  I am relatively new to jquery but have had no luck in researching this topic, including reading similar questions on this site.

```
<script>

$('#joke-form').on('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var words = $('this input: first').val(); 
console.log(words);        
});

if (words === "ANSWER") {
    $('#result').text("You have the right answer");
}
else {
    $('#result').text("Guess again!");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Is your `console.log` logging anything?  I would think that selector would work.  Though since your `input` has an `id` you can simply use: `$('#userinput').val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the code in the wrong place, and the selector you are using is incorrect for the input.

See this codepen on how this could work:

http://codepen.io/KempfCreative/pen/JGRzwm

```
$('#joke-form').on('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var words = $('#joke-form #userinput').val(); 
console.log(words);
  if (words === "ANSWER") {
    $('#result').text("You have the right answer");
}
else {
    $('#result').text("Guess again!");
}
});
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the selector can be just `$('#userinput')` instead of `$('#joke-form #userinput')` since `id`s are unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var words = $('#userinput').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `$('this input: first')` is malformed. Since your `input` element has an `id` anyway, I would just select it by `id` instead. Also you will need to put your if else statement inside the submit function.

Here is a **Live Demo** of your code working in action:

```js
$('#joke-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var words = $('#userinput').val();
  console.log(words);
  
  if (words === "JQUERY") {
    $('#result').text("You have the right answer");
  } else {
    $('#result').text("Guess again!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Word game!</h1>
<form id="joke-form">
  <label>
    Unscramble these letters to form a word:
    <Br>
    <span class="scrambled">REYJUQ</span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="userinput" size="10">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Check</button>
</form>

<span id="result"></span>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/6pd5z9kv/1/

Answer (score 0):

I see many anwsers already but here is what you've done wrong

your code

```
var words = $('this input: first').val();
```

fixed

```
var words = $(this).find("input:first").val();
    //use 'this' seprately, then you start input:first with " and finished with '
```

hopefully it will work for you, and about html I dont know if its copy/pase issue but remove blank space with `id` and `=`

your code

```
id = "userinput"
```

fixed

```
id="userinput"
```

Rest is just fine :) 
Cheers